# Get movies section from wikipedia one by one

Tags: php, curl, mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get movies plot and other information from Wikipedia page. I have movie title and year, from that I have to find the accurate movie and their respective plot, other information.

I am using Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=jsonfm&srsearch=matrix%20incategory:English-language_films.

I am getting the following response

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"continue": {
    "sroffset": 10,
    "continue": "-||"
},
"query": {
    "searchinfo": {
        "totalhits": 176
    },
    "search": [
        {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "The Matrix",
            "pageid": 30007,
            "size": 123422,
            "wordcount": 12668,
            "snippet": "The <span class=\"searchmatch\">Matrix</span> is a 1999 science fiction action film written and directed by the Wachowskis that stars Keanu Reeves, Laurence Fishburne, Carrie-Anne Moss,",
            "timestamp": "2019-05-17T20:53:05Z"
        },
```

I need to search all movies, not only english movies. I need to get plot section text directly from search.

Comment: What API you are using? What data you receiving? What data you want? Can you share some examples?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

First install:

```
$ pip3 install imdbpy wikipedia
```

Then:

```
>>> import wikipedia
>>> from imdb import IMDb
>>> imdb = IMDb()

>>> imdb.search_movie('avengers')
[<Movie id:0848228[http] title:_The Avengers (2012)_>, <Movie id:0203247[http] title:_"Avengers: United They Stand" (1999)_>, <Movie id:2164490[http] title:_Avengers (1987) (VG)_>, <Movie id:4154796[http] title:_Avengers: Endgame (2019)_>, <Movie id:4154756[http] title:_Avengers: Infinity War (2018)_>, <Movie id:2395427[http] title:_Avengers: Age of Ultron (2015)_>, <Movie id:2455546[http] title:_"Avengers Assemble" (2013)_>, <Movie id:1626038[http] title:_"The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes" (2010)_>, <Movie id:0458339[http] title:_Captain America: The First Avenger (2011)_>, <Movie id:0118661[http] title:_The Avengers (1998)_>, <Movie id:0054518[http] title:_"The Avengers" (1961)_>, <Movie id:1355644[http] title:_Passengers (I) (2016)_>, <Movie id:8836988[http] title:_Avengement (I) (2019)_>, <Movie id:0473445[http] title:_Avenger (2006) (TV)_>, <Movie id:9426186[http] title:_Revenger (2018)_>, <Movie id:2378453[http] title:_Avenged (2013)_>, <Movie id:4296026[http] title:_Avengers Grimm (2015) (V)_>, <Movie id:0491703[http] title:_Ultimate Avengers (2006) (V)_>, <Movie id:0090190[http] title:_The Toxic Avenger (1984)_>, <Movie id:0056174[http] title:_The Avenger (1962)_>]

>>> title = imdb.search_movie('avengers')[0].data['title']
'The Avengers'

>>> wiki_page = wikipedia.page(title)

>>> wiki_page.url
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_(comics)'

>>> print(wiki_page.content)
```

See:

- https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/
- https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy

Comment: Can you give an example of the Wikipedia API URL?

Comment: I already have a title from IMDB and other detail. I want the URL to pass the title and get content from Wikipedia.

Comment: Alvas provided a way to get the wiki page in Python. In your tags I see you are using PHP, is that right? I see your question is already downvoted, that is probably because you need to share some more information about what you are trying to to do in what kind of environment/language/framework or whatsoever, so people better understand the problem you are facing so they can help you better.

Comment: I just want to know what are the parameters have to pass to the Wikipedia API in order to get the plot for every movie. If someone knows about Wikipedia API they can answer instantly. Just parameters.

Comment: The API endpoint you metioned in your question returns a JSON with all Wikipedia pages with matrix in its title (so also some math pages). If you know how to distinguish the movie pages from the other (for you irrelevant) pages in a search, you can probably feed the page id to a second API call that gets more info about a page. See `pageids` in the call below, Not sure if this only returns revisions or the whole page content (because the `content=revisions` parameter). But you can verify.
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=30007&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm